# DataReader does not see data in Excel cell if previous cell in the column are empty

Tags: c#, excel, xls, datareader, oledbdatareader

I have a weird problem with reading .xls file using `OleDbDataReader`.

Basically, it does not see a data in the cell, if the previous cells in the column are empty.

If I move the row with the data at the top of Excel sheet, then everything loads fine. I'm not sure, but I think that it has something to do with the amount of empty cells before the one with data.

Any help or advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can verify/falsify your assumption.

Comment: Don't really see a point in posting code. The problem literally disappears if I move problem rows at the top of Excel sheet, i.e.

This does not work: HEADER
                    100 Empty cells
                    Not Empty cell 

This does: HEADER
           7(any small number really) Empty cells 
           NOT Empty cell 

This does too: HEADER
               NOT Empty Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a connectionstring like this:

```
<add name="MyApp.Properties.Settings.ExcelConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text;&quot;;"/>
```

Notice the 'TypeGuessRows'. It tells Excel how many rows to scan to try to guess the datatypes of the columns. The value 0 (zero) tells it to scan all rows. Does that help you?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, GreatBittern.

I actually figured the answer a couple of week before and just forgot to post the solution here. Which I apologies for.